# php forms multiple input upload

Tags: php

I wrote a multiple form, but it doesn't work. Code inspector tells me something is wrong with move_uploaded_file function. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

My HTML code:

```
<div class="setting post">
    <form action="add-banner.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="banner-title" placeholder="enter new banner title"><br>
    <select name="banner-cat">
           <?php
           $get_cats = mysqli_query($db,'select * from cats');
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_cats)){
           ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['cat_name'] ?></option>
           <?php
           }
           ?>
           </select>
           <br>
           <input type="file" name="banner">
           <br>
     <input type="submit" name="upload" value="add new banner">
     </form>
    </div>
```

and this is my php code:

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';
global $db;
$banner_title = $_POST['banner-title'];
$banner_cat = $_POST['banner-cat'];
$banner = $_FILES['banner']['name'];
$banner_tmp = $_FILES['banner']['tmp_name'];
$upload_file = move_uploaded_file($banner_tmp,'../../images/$banner');
$insert_banner = mysqli_query($db,"insert into banner(banner_title,banner_cat,banner_link) values ('$banner_title','$banner_cat','$banner')");
if($insert_banner && $upload_file){
    $message = 'New banner Succesfully added';
    echo "<script>
    alert('".$message."');
    window.location.href='post.php';
    exit;
    </script>";

    }else{$message = 'Something goes Wrong';
    echo "<script>
    alert('".$message."');
    window.location.href='post.php';
    exit;
    </script>"; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: This code has got a lot of vulnerabilities: unsanitized inputs being used to create a query and do filesystem operations. This is a russian roulette with an automatic gun. Google up SQL injection, and look around on how to sanitize your inputs, or your site is in danger.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 require_once 'db.php';
 global $db;
 $banner_title = $_POST['banner-title'];
 $banner_cat = $_POST['banner-cat'];
 $banner = basename($_FILES['banner']['name']);
 $banner_tmp = $_FILES['banner']['tmp_name'];
 $upload_file = move_uploaded_file($banner_tmp,'/images/$banner');
 $insert_banner = mysqli_query($db,"insert into banner(banner_title,banner_cat,banner_link) values ('$banner_title','$banner_cat','$banner')");
 if($insert_banner && $upload_file){
$message = 'New banner Succesfully added';
echo "<script>
alert('".$message."');
window.location.href='post.php';
exit;
</script>";

}else{$message = 'Something goes Wrong';
echo "<script>
alert('".$message."');
window.location.href='post.php';
exit;
</script>"; 
}
?>
```

// Don't use back folder for uploaded file, if use back folder, use full url for folder.